# Show only queries made by EF in SQL Profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, sql-server-profiler

How can I show only queries made by EF in SQL Profiler?

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot the query highlighted in red is the one which I was created with the help of the EF. All the others are generated from somewhere else and I would like to hide them.

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

When I try to specify the `applicationName` in the connection string I get an error.

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) {     

optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.\\;Database=AdventureWorksLT2012;Trusted_Connection=True;applicationName=FOO_NAME");
            }
        }
```

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'applicationname'.
>      at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure you pass an application name in your connections string from EF or have EF use it's own login and filter to that. But you *should* already be doing both of those.

Comment: are you perhaps using CMS or framework? they might be the origin of the other queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your EF DbContext has it's own connection string, you can set ';Application Name=EF' in your connection string and filter in profiler for this application name.

You do it either on the Trace Properties dialog on connecting

- select Events Selection tab
- click button Column filters...
- add your application name in the connection string to the Property ApplicationName. You can use other filters as well, e.g. hostname, if you check 'Show all columns'.

When you are already connected to the server you press the Properties icon in the toolbar and do the same.

[image]

Comment: Could you, please, point to a place in the profiler GUI which I can use to filter for the app name?

Comment: Added, hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. There is yet another issue. Could you, please, help? I updated my question.

Comment: It seems that changing the `applicationName` to the `Application Name` solved the issue.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, that was a typo in the connection string. I fixed my answer